# if statement acting wrong

Tags: python, if-statement

I have input like this:

```
byr:1983 iyr:2017
pid:796082981 cid:129 eyr:2030
ecl:oth hgt:182cm

iyr:2019
cid:314
eyr:2039 hcl:#cfa07d hgt:171cm ecl:#0180ce byr:2006 pid:8204115568

byr:1991 eyr:2022 hcl:#341e13 iyr:2016 pid:729933757 hgt:167cm ecl:gry

hcl:231d64 cid:124 ecl:gmt eyr:2039
hgt:189in
pid:#9c3ea1

ecl:#1f58f9
pid:#758e59
iyr:2022
hcl:z
byr:2016 hgt:68 eyr:1933

hcl:#fffffd ecl:gry eyr:2022
hgt:172cm pid:781914826 byr:1930 iyr:2018

hcl:#08df7e ecl:grn byr:1942
eyr:2028 iyr:2011 cid:141 pid:319110455
hgt:186cm
```

and so on +250 packages(package - set of byr,iyr... separated by empty line) like that.

My code is like this:

```
result_file = open('results.txt', 'w')

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[:3] == 'cid':
            continue
        elif line == "\n":
            result_file.write('\n')
        else:
            line = line.replace('\n','')
            for i in line.split(' '):
                result_file.write(i + '\n')

result_file.close()
```

and it turns my input into this structure:

```
byr:1983
iyr:2017
pid:796082981
cid:129
eyr:2030
ecl:oth
hgt:182cm

iyr:2019
eyr:2039
hcl:#cfa07d
hgt:171cm
ecl:#0180ce
byr:2006
pid:8204115568

byr:1991
eyr:2022
hcl:#341e13
iyr:2016
pid:729933757
hgt:167cm
ecl:gry

hcl:231d64
cid:124
ecl:gmt
eyr:2039
hgt:189in
pid:#9c3ea1

ecl:#1f58f9
pid:#758e59
iyr:2022
hcl:z
byr:2016
hgt:68
eyr:1933
```

but the problem is that line `if line[:3] == 'cid': continue` seems to be working only 'sometimes'(however strange it might sound), and I want to have file like above, but without any cid:value fields.

As always, my reasoning(solution in code) seems to be correct for me, and I can't find out where the mistake is.

Please help. Thanks from advance!

Comment: What does "working" mean in this context, please?

Comment: @ggorlen it means once it skipped the 'cid',and other time not

Comment: I’d guess hidden characters in the input, could you do line.startswith(“cid”) instead?

Comment: Try to find a minimal input file which reproduces your problem. Then post your input, output and desired output.

Comment: The only time `line[:3]` succeds is at the line `cid:314` which it does start with `cid`. What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but the problem is that line if line[:3] == 'cid': continue seems to be working only 'sometimes'(however strange it might sound), and I want to have file like above, but without any cid:value fields.

Seems to be working in every case to me. The issue is that your script only checks if `'cid'` is the first three characters of the *input line*.

In the demonstration input you provide, `cid` is only the start of the line in one case (which is excluded from the output), in every other case it's in the middle of the input line and thus never going to match anything.

If you want to exclude every `cid` entry, you need to do so on the *entries* (the inner loop after the `split`) e.g.

```py
with open('results.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as result_file,\
     open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        for entry in line.rstrip('\n').split(' '):
            if not entry.startswith('cid:'):
                print(entry, file=result_file)
```